# Error when using "panel.ellipse" function in R

Tags: r

I want to draw a confidence ellipse. I search the R document and find the function: panel.ellipse.  Here is the [description website](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/latticeExtra/versions/0.6-28/topics/panel.ellipse)

Then I tried. I used the code below:

```
library(corrgram)
a<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
b<-c(2,4,6,5,3)
panel.ellipse(a, b)
```

But an error occur:

```
Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : 
plot.new has not been called yet
```

I didn't call "plot.new", why did R say that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're linking to the `latticeExtra::panel.ellipse` function in the description link, but seem to be using `corrgram` which also has a `panel.ellipse` function. So I'm not sure which `panel.ellipse` function you are using/want to use.

From `?corrgram::panel.ellipse`:

> ```
> # CAUTION: The latticeExtra package also has a 'panel.ellipse' function
> # that clashes with the same-named function in corrgram. In order to us
> # the right one, the example below uses 'lower.panel=corrgram::panel.ellipse'.
> # If you do not have latticeExtra loaded, you can just use
> # 'lower.panel=panel.ellipse'.
> ```

Why not use `ggplot2::stat_ellipse` instead?

```
# Your sample data
a<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
b<-c(2,4,6,5,3)
df <- cbind.data.frame(a, b);

# Use stat_ellipse to draw confidence ellipse
require(ggplot2);
ggplot(df, aes(a, b)) + geom_point() + stat_ellipse();
```

[image]